# Set Apache outgoing requests to go through a proxy

Tags: apache, proxy

I have a problem with Apache. First I'm using a virtual machine provided by my university faculty. I installed XAMPP on it. I can access to this virtual machine from outside. However, this machine cannot directly connect to external sites to fetch resources. The network admin told me that I have to connect to faculty proxy server in order to get to external sites.

How can I set Apache on my virtual machine to go through proxy for every request made?
I searched and found that I may need to use ProxyRemote but I cannot make it work. The httpd.conf I set was:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ProxyRemote * http://x.x.x.x:yyyy
```

x.x.x.x = faculty proxy ip, yyyy = faculty proxy port

Did I make something wrong or miss something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you may be a little mixed up. Apache does not make requests on its own. You have an application that is running on Apache, and that application needs to request resources from outside.  You need to configure either your application or your VM's entire network interface to make requests through the external proxy. Apologies if I misread your question.

Comment: Yes you're right I want to make my web applications connect to external sources, eg: fetching webpage content. But now it's impossible as I cannot directly connect to any external sites, I have to configure a proxy for every request. Can I force all request under my web app to use proxy. I find it impractical to set proxy for every single request. It's even worse when I use APIs (it's timed out as API cannot fetch any data and I cannot go through every line of code and add proxy).

Comment: Which virtual machine are you using? VMware? Virtualbox? Check the VM settings and try switching the network adapter to NAT mode if it's not already.

Comment: Actually the virtual machine is allocated by the network admin. I have no control over it. All I can do is using remote desktop or VMware vSphere Client to connect to it.

Comment: You may be out of luck then :/ the requests your applications make do not pass through your local Apache at all unless you explicitly tell them to. And if you're going to do that you may as well tell them to use a proxy instead.

Comment: You mean I have to do it programmatically every time my code fetch content from outside? There is no way I could force every app under Apache to go through a proxy server specified?

Comment: Like I said, when your apps request content from outside, they do not go through your local Apache at all. They attempt to make direct socket connections to the external resources. Changing your local Apache would have no effect on these requests.

Comment: It's very unfortunate to me then :(.
What can you recommend? what if I force at PHP level to use proxy for every request?

Comment: It is unfortunate. All I can recommend is that you ask your network admin for suggestions - perhaps they can set up a proxy on your VM instance. Hopefully someone else will come along with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyRemote http://www.example.com http://pac.group.intranet:8080
```

This seems to work. For the network proxy part at least. (I'm having my fair share of other problems at ["Invalid URI in request" trying to proxy iframe content for local debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268223/invalid-uri-in-request-trying-to-proxy-iframe-content-for-local-debugging).)