# "Invalid URI in request" trying to proxy iframe content for local debugging

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm trying to debug a problem in a page that contains an iframe. The site serving the parent page is code I'm working on that I can easily run locally, but the content of the iframe comes from code I don't have access to. There's some protection blocking cross-domain iframing, which won't be a problem in production, because there they'll run on the same domain. However, I need to debug something locally, so I'm using Apache to proxy the site.

Also, the internal network I'm on uses a proxy which Apache has to take into account.

My apache config so far: (note that I totally suck at apache configuration)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.aspx(.*)$   https://www.example.com/$1.aspx$2   [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.aspx$   https://www.example.com/$1.aspx   [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/static/(.+)$   https://www.example.com/static/$1   [PT,L]
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]


#SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests On
ProxyRemote http://www.example.com http://pac.group.intranet:8080
ProxyRemote https://www.example.com http://pac.group.intranet:8080
```

The `aspx` and `/static/` stuff is the other site that I'm trying to proxy here. My own site is running on port 8080.

I'm currently getting a `Invalid URI in request` on a request that looks totally normal. At some point it seemed to be accepting my request, then it complained about SSL, so I added `SSLProxyEngine On`. It's currently off, which doesn't generate a SSL error, so clearly the problem occurs before that.

After I added `SSLProxyEngine On`, it basically worked except that I wasn't proxying the static resources for the other site yet. So I added the `/static/` line, and then I got my current problem.

I've spent way too much time on this already and I just can't figure it out. I can't find any clear examples or tutorials explaining how to do this. It seems like such an obvious thing to do, but I just can't get it working. But removing it now won't fix it. Basically, Apache seems to act totally unpredictably. I don't understand this well enough to understand why.

Any idea what's causing this problem and how to finally get it working?

I'm using XAMPP 3.2.1 on Windows.

Log details:

```
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:38.879301 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3248:tid 220] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:38.924310 2014] [core:warn] [pid 3248:tid 220] AH00098: pid file C:/Workset/tools/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:39.262377 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3248:tid 220] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:39.309387 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3248:tid 220] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:39.309387 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3248:tid 220] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:39.309387 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3248:tid 220] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\workset\\tools\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Workset/tools/xampp/apache'
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:39.310387 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3248:tid 220] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7668
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:40.066538 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 7668:tid 232] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:40.441613 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 7668:tid 232] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:40.489623 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7668:tid 232] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Jun 19 14:25:43.904305 2014] [core:error] [pid 7668:tid 1680] [client ::1:56999] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /foo/search/welcome.aspx?ask=bar HTTP/1.1
[Thu Jun 19 14:26:00.705665 2014] [core:error] [pid 7668:tid 1680] [client ::1:57001] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /foo/search/welcome.aspx?ask=bar HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Does your apache error log show anything telling? I'm not sure if apache-level errors even get reported there, thought its the first thing I would look at if I has a problem.

Comment: If your project is just development then use http. It may be that something your doing or something that loaded content is doing requires https and the other piece is providing http.

Comment: The apache error log says `[Thu Jun 19 14:25:43.904305 2014] [core:error] [pid 7668:tid 1680] [client ::1:56999] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /foo/search/welcome.aspx?ask=bar HTTP/1.1
[Thu Jun 19 14:26:00.705665 2014] [core:error] [pid 7668:tid 1680] [client ::1:57001] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET /foo/search/welcome.aspx?ask=bar HTTP/1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working, and I'm sharing the solution here for posterity:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(/.+)\.aspx(.*)$   https://www.example.com$0
ProxyPass /static    https://www.example.com/
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests On
ProxyRemote http://www.example.com http://pac.group.intranet:8080
ProxyRemote https://www.example.com http://pac.group.intranet:808
```

It's actually much cleaner this way. Not relying on rewrite rules and using `ProxyPassMatch` for the regexp is basically the core of the solution.